# Using stack bars in a combination chart

Tags: data-visualization, spotfire

I am putting together a combination chart that shows count of binned values and the sum of an amount related to those bins. I have another attribute (days to process) which comprise those bars. Is it possible to stack the bar chart by the categories in this type of visualization.

The top picture is the chart I want to use, the bottom chart shows how I want the bars to appear in my top chart.

Would appreciate any advice on how to get this result. Thanks!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Kind of hard to tell without some data but if your right click on your combo chart and clicked stacked bars will it allow you?

Answer (score 0):

There is an Option under Properties>Appearance for Bars layout to select between Stacked Bar and Side by Side bars. Using this we can achieve stack bars in combination charts.